# Wildfly 10 getting a NullPointerException while running in domain mode

Tags: java, apache, httpd.conf, wildfly-10, mod-cluster

I have configured Wildfly 10 in domain mode.

All configuration of Apache HTTP Sever and mode_cluster are done.

There are 2 hosts. One is master and other is slave.

There are total 4 instances of Wildfly on both hosts, 2 on each hosts.

While executing wildfly on master and slave I am getting a `NullPointerException` as following:

> ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (INT-2,ee,slave1:server-two)
>   JGRP000030: slave1:server-two: failed handling incoming message:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Made lot of google but did not find any solution for this.

Why is NullPointerException is there and how can it be rectified ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the problem is the connection between the two servers, while discovering each other. But I need a stacktrace to be more specific..

Comment: What is showing in your Apache's "error.log"? If there is no important information of this problem, change the Apache log level.